# Heroku custom domain currently in use by another app. How can I find which app is using it?

Tags: heroku

I have run into trouble a few times when adding custom domains to an app in heroku. 
The Heroku team I'm on has hundreds of heroku apps. It would be tedious to look at the settings of each one to try and find where a custom domain has been set in order to remove it. Is there a way to list all custom domains in use for the entire account?

I have run into this twice now with one "currently in use by another app error" and with one "another app is using a wildcard domain". Heroku does provide a way to contact support to remove the custom domain https://tools.heroku.support/domain-release but this requires DNS verification and might take some time. I'd like to know what app is using it before having it removed.

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I combine a few different scripts to come up with the following console command to use if you have the Heroku CLI installed:

```
for site (`heroku list -t my-team`); do echo `heroku domains --app $site`; done;
```

This outputs all the Heroku apps and configured custom domains into the console which I could then search to see which app the custom domain was configured on.